Determine the linear transformation based on minor/dimension of its transformation matrix
Suppose we have a linear transformation $T$, $$T:\mathbb R^m\rightarrow\mathbb R^n$$
Then the transformation $T$ can be represented by a $m\times n$ matrix $M$.

A linear transformation is surjective if every vector in its range is in its image. Equivalently, at least one $n\times n$ minor of the $n\times m$ matrix is invertible.


It is injective if every vector in its image is the image of only one vector in its domain. Equivalently, at least one $m\times m$ minor of the $n\times m$ matrix is invertible.

I couldn't understand how the former one is equivalent to latter one. Specially, the at least part and specific dimensional minor searching seem very confusing. Like, I thought any $n (\textrm{a portion of the rows})\times n (\textrm{full length column})$ minor may give a portion of the $\operatorname{Im}(T)$. Then isn't it should be all minor instead of at least one? Another question is, I see if $m\geq n$ then $T$ can't be injective. Is there any similar check for surjective? Because the only test I came so far is find $\operatorname{Ker}(T)$ and find $\dim\operatorname{Im}(T)$ which is $n-\dim\operatorname{Ker}(T)$ then see if it is equal to $m$ or not.
I am more interested in some intuitive answer rather a complete proof. Any help will be appreciated. TIA

Consider the cases where $T(u,v,w) \to (u,v)$ and $T(u,v) \to (u,v,0)$.

The first one is surjective and second one is injective. @CyclotomicField

Good. What can you say about their minors?

For the first one, there is no $3\times 3$ minor. And One $2\times 2$ minor $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ which is invertible @CyclotomicField Still I didn't see the complete picture.

Check the other minors. You'll find one of them is not invertible in each case.

Other minors are not invertible, $\left{ \pmatrix{1&0\0&0},  \pmatrix{0&1\0&0}\right}$ which align with the statement. But for the second transformation, there is no $3\times 3$ minor, as $M=\pmatrix{1&0\0&1\0&0}$ although it's injective. Is it because we have vacuously true case here? @CyclotomicField

Be careful with the $n$ and the $m$. You're looking at $2\times 2$ minors in both cases.
